# How to find string in .txt file using regex?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to find: `9ozrhtdy1uq31` in this single line text file:

```
[{"kind": "Listing", "data": {"modhash": "", "dist": 1, "children": [{"kind": "t3", "data": {"approved_at_utc": null, "subreddit": "blackmagicfuckery", "selftext": "", "user_reports": [], "saved": false, "mod_reason_title": null, "gilded": 0, "clicked": false, "title": "Electron-filled acrylic cylinder at my work. Sorry for the dark video", "link_flair_richtext": [], "subreddit_name_prefixed": "r/blackmagicfuckery", "hidden": false, "pwls": 6, "link_flair_css_class": null, "downs": 0, "thumbnail_height": 140, "parent_whitelist_status": "all_ads", "hide_score": false, "name": "t3_ddxfse", "quarantine": false, "link_flair_text_color": "dark", "upvote_ratio": 0.98, "author_flair_background_color": null, "subreddit_type": "public", "ups": 16387, "total_awards_received": 1, "media_embed": {}, "thumbnail_width": 140, "author_flair_template_id": null, "is_original_content": false, "author_fullname": "t2_wk8jx", "secure_media": {"reddit_video": {"fallback_url": "https://v.redd.it/9ozrhtdy1uq31/DASH_1080?source=fallback", "height": 1080, "width": 608, "scrubber_media_url": "https://v.redd.it/9ozrhtdy1uq31/DASH_96", "dash_url": "https://v.redd.it/9ozrhtdy1uq31/DASHPlaylist.mpd", "duration": 16, "hls_url": "https://v.redd.it/9ozrhtdy1uq31/HLSPlaylist.m3u8", "is_gif": false, "transcoding_status": "completed"}}, "is_reddit_media_domain": true, "is_meta": false, "category": null, "secure_media_embed": {}, "link_flair_text": null, "can_mod_post": false, "num_duplicates": 9, "approved_by": null, "thumbnail": "https://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/1LMEGlpcGamc412rcLqCch3Do36LaxvUHTzJePkJOdQ.jpg", "edited": false,
```

Then have `9ozrhtdy1uq31` for later use.

So far I have basically nothing but confusion. I have read other questions asking parts of my needs some using `findstr` and `for /F` and Im not sure which to use.

Can anyone help or just find some good resources I can use?

Comment: I would suggest that your file is processed by a language better designed for such a task, batch files without at least leveraging another scripting language or command line tool are not a wise decision.

Comment: @glenta can you tell me which API did you use to get such JSON reply ?  and what's your aim to get the ID inside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract this `ID=9ozrhtdy1uq31` from URL in your JSON file, you should try with Regex in vbscript like this code :

```bat
@echo off & color 0A
Title Extract ID from URL using Regex in Vbscript
Set "InputFile=%~dp0file.txt"
Call :Extract_ID "%InputFile%" ID
Echo The ID extracted is %ID%
Pause & Exit
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Extract_ID <InputFile> <ID to be Set>
(
echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Extract_ID(Data^)
echo Function Extract_ID(Data^)
echo      Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll  
echo      Set re = New RegExp 
echo      re.Global = True 
echo      re.IgnoreCase = True  
echo      re.Pattern = "https:\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+\/([\w]*[\w])(/HLSPlaylist.m3u8)" 
echo      For Each Match in re.Execute(Data^) 
echo          ID = Match.SubMatches(1^) 
echo      Next  
echo     Extract_ID = ID
echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" ^< "%~1"') do set "%2=%%A"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

***Edit :***

Or you can also use Regex in Powershell :

```bat
@echo off & color 0A
Title Extract ID from URL using Regex in Powershell
Set "InputFile=%~dp0file.txt"
Set psCmd="&{$content=Get-Content -Path '%InputFile%';[regex]$regex='https:\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+\/([\w]*[\w])(/HLSPlaylist.m3u8)';$regex.Matches($content).captures.groups[2].value}"
Call :RunPS %psCmd% ID
Echo The ID extracted is %ID%
pause & Exit
::----------------------------------------------------------------------
:RunPS <PassPSCMD> <RetValue>
  for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`Powershell %1`) do set "%2=%%i"
Goto:eof
:: End of :RunPS function
::----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How would I use the Regex in Powershell script for just basic user imputed strings?